# strange String.start_with? behaviour

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple ruby script that reads URLs from a txt file and then downloads these files.

The txt file may contain comments which have a trailing `#` character.

I am reading the file line by line, chomp and strip each line and then check each line if it starts with a `#` sign.

Now I have the problem that `line.start_with?("#")` always returns false even though the line starts with a leading #.

I checked the characters and found out that at `line[0]` there is indeed no `#` character; it is at `line[1]`.

Can sb. explain what is going on here? Has it st to do with the file's UTF-8 character encoding?

Thx!

Comment: do you have a space in front of the #?

Comment: it seems that the problem is the file encoding. If I save the file in UTF-8 the first character is some invisible byte and not the #. If I save the file in Latin-1 it works. But how can I handle this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `puts line.inspect` to see whether there's anything in the string you haven't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try stripping first, eg

```
line.strip.start_with?("#")
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're stripping the strings before checking things. But, I'm guessing that you're still getting leading whitespace. So, are you calling [`strip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001189) or [`strip!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001196)? The plain `strip` method returns the stripped string but does not change the string, the `strip!` version changes the string in place; if you're just using `strip` then you might be unknowingly throwing away the stripped string and then getting confused by the leading or trailing whitespace that is still there.

Similar issues may apply to your use of [`chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001188) when you want [`chomp!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001195).

Furthermore, there's no need to use both `chomp` and `strip`, just `strip` (or `strip!`) is sufficient as `chomp` is, more or less, just a restricted version of [`rstrip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001191) which in turn is, essentially, just a `strip` applied to only the end of the string.

Comment: I chomp! and strip! the line before I check it for the starting # character. I am using chomp! because I want to make sure that any record separators (\n, \t) are removed as well. According to ruby-doc strip! only removes leading and trailing whitespaces

Comment: @behas: `\n` and `\t` are whitespace (as is `\r` and a few other things), the `strip` documentation (see my link) even includes an example with `\t` and `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for my problem: [strange characters at beginning of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660006/strange-characters-at-beginning-of-file)

...but not the solution.